# Weblogic connection pool

Tags: weblogic, weblogic8.x

I'm trying to create a connection pool in weblogic (8.1) and getting the following exception:

```
<BEA-001129> <Received exception while creating connection for pool "testPool": 7>
```

I have no clue about that number (7). How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a DB side error. Pls check if you are able to connect to the target DB using any other client. That might give a clue.